# Storing state in Go

Tags: architecture, go, coding-style, global-variables, information-hiding

I'm writing a simple program in Go as an exercise to learn the language. The program is a game player: it `exec.Command`s a text-based game, then communicates with it via `StdinPipe`/`StdoutPipe`. After some fooling around and reading a lot of online docs I managed to get the skeleton working -- the equivalent of Hello World, where I've established two-way communication and can handle errors like the program terminating.

Now I'm trying to write the actual game-playing AI code. Since my purpose is learning the language, I'm trying to be very careful with style -- I don't just want to write C (or some other language) in Go.

The obvious division of labor in the program (once all the setup is done) is into two parts. First, the program looks at the current state and decides what command should be issued to the game. Second, the program looks at the data returned and updates the state accordingly. (Yes, it's a simple game -- it waits for input and then responds, there are no timing issues.)

I'm not sure where this state information should go. Dumping it all into the global scope feels wrong, and making a massive singleton object seems even worse (and Go isn't particularly OO). In any case I don't want to have the functions pass and return 20+ variables.

General advice is fine, but I'm most interested in what is idiomatically appropriate for Go. On request I can share code but I don't think it would be helpful.

Comment: this is such an interesting project - I'm writing something similar and could learn from your work - did you happen to open source it on Github or publish it anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go does enable a [style of OO programming](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language).

Create a struct type for the game state. Pass a pointer to a value of this type around in your program or store the pointer in a package level variable if that sort of thing does not bother you. Implement methods on this type as needed. Consider putting it in its own package for greater encapsulation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you don't mind I'll wait until tomorrow to accept an answer -- I'm still mulling over what solution is best. (+1 in the meantime.)

Answer (score 6):

I like using a package for this purpose.

trivial example:

```
package foo

func Incr() {
    f.incr()
}

func Count() int {
    return f.count()
}

type foo struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    count int
}

func (f *foo) incr() {
    f.Lock()
    f.count++
    f.Unlock()
}

func (f *foo) count() int {
    f.RLock()
    defer f.RUnlock()
    return f.count
}

var f = &foo{}
```

This package can be imported into any other package and maintain state.  I added the sync.RWMutex to prevent any race conditions.  This gives you complete control of how foo's state is accessed and is nicely contained.

Comment: Thanks. Let me make sure I understand your suggestion: I make a `struct` which holds all my state variables, then instantiate it as a global object so I can check and modify state in my updating functions. Correct? (And of course I +1'd you.)

Comment: @Charles Correct. You could store any state you wanted on the struct and add methods to that struct if you like.  The positive to this approach is that you can completely control access and easily import the state into other packages.  Go's net/http package takes a similar approach with the HandlerFunc and Handler methods allowing you to add http handlers in multiple packages.

Comment: @tommywild can you elaborate? It's pretty easy to add foo_test and test anything in the package. You could also easily test the above functionality using the exported methods.

Comment: @tommywild I see what you are saying. I edited the answer so foo has an incr and count method, this will allow testing of foo independently of f's state.

Comment: @tommywild I briefly deleted this answer, thought about it for a while and am now un-deleting it.  My rational: In a game (or most programs) you will need some way to maintain state. The above approach allows for thread safe access to the games state and allows for any part of the program to have easy access to said state without having to pass the state to every function. I think this approach should be used sparingly but some amount of pragmatism goes a long way.